# MySQL creating structural relationship between tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have 2 tables, one is containing items and their properties, which are integers:

**items table:**

```
item_id, property_a, property_b, property_c
```

and another, *single-row* table, which contains allowed deviations of these properties,
also integers:

**allowed deviations table:**

```
property_a, property_b, property_c
```

This works, but there's no formal relationship between 2 tables hence no way to assure they're in sync when items table is modified in any way (except taking care of it manually or on application level).

So my question is - What's the best practice for this situation? Could and should some kind of relation between structure of these 2 tables be made on a database level, or it's good as it is?

One of my thoughts was, as deviations is a single row table, to just put it in items table, giving it specific dummy item, but the problems I see with that is:

-- dummy data, don't like that in my so far clean database
-- complicating queries that relate to items only
-- mixing apples and oranges in a single table
-- making it hard to extend if there's ever need for multiple sets of allowed deviations

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need to do a bit of normalisation here.

You could go with the following approach:

**item table**

```
id  item
1   item1
```

**item_property table**

```
id  item_id, property_id
1     1         1
2     1         2
3     1         3
```

**allowed deviations table**

```
property_id, property_type
1               a
2               b
3               c
```

This will allow you to set up a FK constraints on the item_property table referencing both the allowed deviations table and the item table itself. It should also allow for items that do not have all properties (without null data) and it should also allow you to add in new properties should any new ones come along (for example property d).

Hope this helps!

PS When you say "One of my thoughts was, as deviations is a single column table" do you mean "One of my thoughts was, as deviations is a single *row* table"?

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant row, question edited. I'm not quite sure I fully get your answer though - the deviations table would hold property definitions as rows, is that the proposal? If so, the downside of it would be if there's need for another set of deviations, that would require a new column, which may not be the best practice to organize data.

Comment: Yes. The idea is to hold the property definitions as rows. My thoughts are that if there is another set of allowed deviations (say d, e and f) this would mean 3 new rows inserted into the deviations table and the item_property table to be populated with the items to which the new set of deviations are applicable. It shouldn't require a new column to be added. Hope that makes sense!